# How to force sync between 64 bit registry and 32 bit registry

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I have 2 windows machines. On one of them the registry get reflected to the WOW6432Node registry and the other one it doesn't which is causing key not found errors.

The code doesn't change at all between the 2 machines (the program is too large to post here). I can't figure out why it is not being reflected. Is there a way to check if the registry reflector is on and working, or is there a way to force the reflection to happen?

Comment: Is the program in question 32bit or 64bit? Is WOW64 even installed on the machine that is not reflecting?

Comment: @RemyLebeau how can I tell if wow64 is installed/enabled? I never touched any wow64 settings os I imagine it would be

Comment: Also should note that there are some keys that exist in the WOW6432Node registry, just not all of them

Comment: On some versions of Windows, WOW64 is an optional component that can be skipped during OS installation. I don't know of any way to test if it is installed after the fact. But it sounds like your system has it installed.

Comment: You haven't diagnosed the problem correctly yet. You need to do that first.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is built-in to WOW64's Registry access. You can't force a reflection sync, it "just happens" in real-time as data is being accessed. All you can do is turn it on and off as needed, per MSDN documentation:

[Registry Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-reflection)

> To disable and enable registry reflection for a particular reflected key, use the [`RegDisableReflectionKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regdisablereflectionkey) and [`RegEnableReflectionKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenablereflectionkey) functions. These functions do not affect keys that are not on the list of reflected keys earlier in this topic. Applications should disable reflection only for the registry keys that they create and not attempt to disable reflection for the predefined keys such as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. To determine whether the keys on the reflection list have been disabled, use the [`RegQueryReflectionKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryreflectionkey) function.